# Using a while loop to split an integer into digits, then multiply digits together

Tags: javascript, parsing, while-loop, split

Attempting a codewars kate (Persistent Bugger) where you have to take an integer and multiply the digits together until the result is < 10 (the answer is the number of times it takes to get under 10).

E.g 39 === 3 because:

1. 3*9 = 27,
2. 2*7 = 14,
3. 1*4 = 4

My logic is to use a while loop, so while multipliedNum > 10, Split integer into individual digits, multiply digits together (each time increasing a count by 1), then if the result is < 10, returning the count.

My issue is, I'm not sure where I'm going wrong with this code, it's not returning anything:

```
function persistence(num) {
  let multipliedNum = num;
  let count = 0;

  while (multipliedNum > 10) {
    multipliedNum = (num + '').split('').reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
      parseInt(previousValue, 10) * parseInt(currentValue, 10));
    count += 1;
  }

  if (multipliedNum < 10) {
    return count;
  }
}

persistence(39);
```

Any clue as to where I'm going wrong would be great! (a bit of a JS beginner here)

Comment: Given that the end result is 4, why does 39 === 3? And what should happen in the even that `multipliedNum` is `10`?

Comment: @DavidThomas because its counting the number of times taken to get to 4, not the end result

Comment: Ahhh; the edit was to(try) and make it clear that it’s the number of steps, not the end result. If I’ve not helped please feel free to rollback.

Comment: Don't fix the code in the question. It invalidates answers.

Comment: @JohnKugelman Code isn't fixed - still doesn't work, just updated an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a different check for the while loop, because you need to include `10` for multiplying.

Then you need the same variable for reducing and assingning. You could take `num` for it. It does not harm if you recycle the same variable for the same purpose.

Then take a simplified callback for reduce, `parseInt` is not necessary, because of the implicit type casting to number by using the multiplication operand `*`. This operator expects numbers and tries to cast the operands to numbers.

At the end just return the count - without a check, which is never `false`.

```js
function persistence(num) {
    var count = 0;

    while (num > 9) {
        num = num.toString().split('').reduce((a, b) => a * b);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}

console.log(persistence(39));
```

Answer (score 1):

The main problem with the code is that, it is stuck in an infinite loop, because of the condition :

```
while(multipliedNum > 10)
```

Because you keep on splinting `num` and assign that to multipliedNum , therefore multipliedNum is always greater than 10.

Try the following:

```js
function persistence(num) {
  let multipliedNum = num;
  let count = 0;

  while (multipliedNum > 10) {
    multipliedNum = (multipliedNum + '').split('').reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
      parseInt(previousValue, 10) * parseInt(currentValue, 10));
    count += 1;
  }
  if (multipliedNum < 10) {
    return count;
  }
}

console.log(persistence(39));
```

Comment: @daggett it returns 3.

Answer (score 1):

**@daggett**, if you prefer to use **recursion** then following code will also work for your problem but I do not recommend you to use this.

I just presented to solve your problem using **recursion** which is a great concept used in large applications to simply the tasks.

Sample log for inputs **39** and **336**

```
3 * 9 = 27
2 * 7 = 14
1 * 4 = 4
============
3 times


7 * 8 * 6 = 336
3 * 3 * 6 = 54
5 * 4 = 20
2 * 0 = 0
============
4 times
```

Code

```js
function timeToGetNumberLessThan10(num) {
 var s = '' + num
 var chars = []

 if(s.length == 1)
  return 1

 sum = 1

 for(var i=0; i < s.length; i++) {
  chars.push(s[i])
  sum *= parseInt(s[i])
 }

 // Log message
 console.log(chars.join(' * ') + ' = ' + sum) 

 if(sum < 10) {
  return 1
 } else {
  // Recursive call
  return 1 + timeToGetNumberLessThan10(sum)
 }
}


// TEST 1
var count = timeToGetNumberLessThan10(39);
console.log('============')
console.log(count + ' times')

console.log('\n') // New line

// TEST 2
var count = timeToGetNumberLessThan10(786);
console.log('============')
console.log(count + ' times')

/*
3 * 9 = 27
2 * 7 = 14
1 * 4 = 4
============
3 times


7 * 8 * 6 = 336
3 * 3 * 6 = 54
5 * 4 = 20
2 * 0 = 0
============
4 times
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (multipliedNum > 10) {
  multipliedNum = (num + '').split('').reduce((previousValue, currentValue) =>
    parseInt(previousValue, 10) * parseInt(currentValue, 10));
  count += 1;
}
```

You're assigning the result to `multipliedNum` but using `num` to start with, which means it keeps splitting the same `num` over and over. Change `num` to `multipliedNum`.